# How to wake a thread in UART RX completed callback

Tags: stm32, uart, rtos

I have a project using STM32F7-Discovery, and I have a couple of threads including UART thread with real time priority.

I use `HAL_UART_Receive_IT()` to get data,then I use `osSignalWait( 0x01, osWaitForever)` while I receive call-back interruption. I have verified that the interruption is occured, but the problem is when I want to wake my uart thread by `osSignalSet( UART_ThreadId, 0x01 )`, the micro controller is hanging.

How can I wake my uart thread ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to properly format it - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Please edit to add any details in order to identify the specific problem. Good luck!

Comment: You have not mentioned *which* RTOS or API you are using.  `osSignalSet()` looks like CMSIS.  If that is the case it may be worth tagging it as such or mentioning it in the text.  Also the STM32Cube API is by no means ubiquitous on STM32, so you should mention that too.

Comment: Rather than *describe* the code; it would be far better to *post* the code, or at least the relevant fragments.

Comment: The thread is four years old, but the essential information (@Clifford asked for) is still missing. I'm voting to close it.